# Элементы div не отображаются в линию

Tags: css, css3, html5

Такая вот проблема, необходимо, чтобы картинки отображались горизонтально и их width был равен div images, а также была возможность их скролить. Но сейчас они отображаются сжимаясь и если добавить 10 изображений, то получается непонятно, что.

```css
.images {
    height:200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    align-items: left;
}

.images .image {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.images .img {
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
                    <div class="image">
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="image">
                            <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="image">
                            <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="image">
                            <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="image">
                            <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://sun1-87.userapi.com/c204816/v204816508/261ed/fwxp6D6bZf8.jpg?ava=1');"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.images .image { min-width: 100%; }`

Comment: Большое спасибо! :)

Comment: @Filvin, не за что, желаю успехов!